# Which one is Better in creating a Tsql Table

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2

I will have two set of data that will be inserted in my table with same fields, they have just different meaning based on the Type of Data Inserted

For Example 
i have inserted

```
                 Albert 2013/1/1 (LoanMonth)
                 Albert 2013/1/1 (AccountinMonth)
```

they have both the same field the treatment of them is the one that would be different

my first approach is that
i will have two dates in my database

namely :

```
ID nvarchar(20)
LoanDate smalldatetime
AccountingDate smalldatetime
```

if i insert the data above the resulting table would be

```
    ID  LOANDATE    AccountingDate
Albert  2013/1/1    null
albert  null        2013/1/1
```

my Second Approach is to have status ID

Namely:

```
ID nvarchar(20)
Date smalldatetime
StatusID bit
```

**1 for Accounting 0 for LoanDate

So the resulting table would be like

```
 ID      DATE      Status
Albert  2013/1/1     0
albert  2013/1/1     1
```

The question would be. what will be the better/best practice among the two?

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.
Thank YOU.

Comment: If the record will eventually have two dates, then you will be better with two date columns.

Comment: @miltonb no they will not have two dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use two different tables.  One for loans and one for accounts.  The reason is you don't want to store objects in the same table that behave differently.  It is hard to tell them apart and you introduce a lot of overheard in your table if you have to do a filter every time you do a select just to get down to the 50% of your rows that are loan dates.  SQL Sever will just default to a slow table scan most of the time.  Since the two accounts are logically different, I think splitting them apart will make for cleaner design and easier SQL statements.

Also, don't use N varchar unless you need the extra characters. Otherwise it is just a waste of space.